# Where to write 'processing code' in an asp.net mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in my controller to read and excel into datatable and do 'bulk sql insert'. I read many documents related to putting the code in model but not sure how to separate the code based on asp.net mvc patterns.

```
static void ReadExcelFileSAX(string fileName)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (SpreadsheetDocument ssd = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
        {
            WorkbookPart wbp = ssd.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.WorksheetParts.First();

            OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(wsp);
            string text;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellValue))
                {
                    sb.Append(reader.GetText()+"\r\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should create a service layer, and in controller you can code the service to read/write xls file

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is async what you are looking for or is this simply a matter of adding some abstractions?